# Create destination folder on FTP server, if it does not exist yet, using WinSCP in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ftp, winscp, winscp-net

I have this script and I want to transfer archive witch script created previous to the server. But on the server I want to check and create if the target folder with name of the machine (`$inputID`) exists or not.

```
$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
    Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Ftp
    HostName = "10.10.10.10"
    PortNumber = 2121
    UserName = "user"
    Password = "pass"
    FtpSecure = [WinSCP.FtpSecure]::Explicit
    TlsHostCertificateFingerprint = "-"
}

$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session

try
{
    # Connect
    $session.Open($sessionOptions)

    # Transfer files
    # Check if $inputID folder exists, if not create it.
    # After, copy the .$inputID - $Date.zip in folder > $inpudID.
    $session.PutFiles(
        "E:\logs\win\Archive\$inputID - $Date.zip", "/Public/$inputID/*").Check()
}
finally
{
    $session.Dispose()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Session.FileExists` method](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_fileexists) and [`Session.CreateDirectory` method](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_createdirectory):

```
$remotePath = "/Public/$inputID"
if (!$session.FileExists($remotePath))
{
    $session.CreateDirectory($remotePath)
}
```

---

*And it's more straightforward and safe to use [`Session.PutFileToDirectory`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_putfiletodirectory):*

```
$session.PutFileToDirectory(
    "E:\logs\win\Archive\$inputID - $Date.zip", $remotePath)
```